# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: https, angular

In my angular2 app I making a HTTPS post request to the API:

```
this.http.post('https://myhost.com/api/users/sign_in', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
      .subscribe(
      response => {.....
```

And I am getting "failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"

Everything was fine with `HTTP` until I switched to `HTTPS`.

I am using self signed certificate for myhost.com.

In browser I am able to accept the certificate and make a request to the API. Could I resolve this also to make an API request via `http.post` from angular2 directly?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857340/err-insecure-response-handing-tips-in-javascript Doesn't look angular related.

Comment: What does ssllabs.com says about your domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)