# Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am getting errors that **XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http://apiurl/signup" Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401** and **OPTIONS 401 Unauthorized**

**CORS** is enabled in **Server Side** and in **browser**.

I am new to **Angular 2**

[image: form to be sent to the server console][image: Response]

Http Service Code

```
signup(form : any)
{
 const body = JSON.stringify(form);
 console.log("HTTP",body);

const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
 ,'Authorization':'Basic <key>' 
});
 let options = new RequestOptions({headers : headers});
  return this.http.post('http://--/signup',body,options).map((data:Response) => data.json())._catch(this.handleError).subscribe(
     err => this.logError(err),
     () =>console.log('Authentification Complete')
     );
}

logError(err) {
  console.error('There was an error: ' + err);}
```

Comment: did you try this with postman?

Comment: What about using `https`?

Comment: after using https it gives net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error 

@sebaferreras

Comment: You should look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461724/authentication-error-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-405][1]

Comment: Seems like a certificate issue. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857340/err-insecure-response-handing-tips-in-javascript)

Comment: On Postman it is working fine @Sampath

Comment: I figured out this error by inspecting my app on Internet explorer.
My app is working fine on IE 
But i didn't find a solution to run my app on chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: I found a solution that how we can run our app on chrome

just open your command prompt

and execute this line    


<--   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session2" --disable-web-security -->


When ever you want to run your app you have to run this command